# Why is power level area under the autocorrelation function of the white-noise signal?

Tags: autocorrelation, signal-power, white-noise

A paper I am reading ([Linear and Nonlinear Encoding Properties of an Identified Mechanoreceptor on the Fly Wing Measured with Mechanical Noise Stimuli](https://journals.biologists.com/jeb/article/151/1/219/5672/Linear-and-Nonlinear-Encoding-Properties-of-an)) defines power level for a white-noise signal as the area under the autocorrelation function of the signal.

What exactly is power level? I couldn't find a proper definition for it. Is it average or RMS power?

Should I take the autocorrelation in frequency domain or time domain?

```
autocorrStim = conv(stim,-stim);
powerLevel = sum(autocorrStim);
```

stim is the white-noise signal. Is this implementation correct?

[image: excerpt of relevant line in the paper]

Excerpt from a textbook on white-noise analysis (Marmarelis and Marmarelis, 1978)
[image]

Comment: hey, they probably (? we don't know what Dickinson 1992a really is… please provide an actual citation!) just mean the *power* when they say *power level*. *Power* is, well, the physical entity power; seeing that they're defining this through the ACF, that is the expected power over an infinitely long observation interval of a weak-sense stationary process. So, it's *expected*, not "average" nor "RMS"; these two terms are something you apply to a deterministic signal or an observation that's already done, whereas expectation is a quality of a random variable.

Comment: That seems wrong. The power is typically $<x^2[n]> = r_{xx}[0]$. I.e. it's the zero tap of the autocorrelation, not the sum over the whole thing.

Comment: Sorry for not sharing the correct citation earlier. I have added the image of the relevant lines from the paper. Thanks for the explanation about power in deterministic signal. The signal I have is a finite length white noise that I have recorded (feedback of mechanically delivered white noise stimulus). So, can I treat it as deterministic signal?

Comment: @Hilmar I have added a screenshot from the textbook. According to the textbook, the total power delivered is given by the integral of the power spectrum. Am I reading it correctly?.

Comment: @user3581147 so, yes, you're right, integral over the PSD, and Hilmar is right, ACF at 0; the text you cited/highlighted in yellow is in contradiction to the formula (and is thus wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the first book is misquoting the second book. The second book says nothing about integrating the autocorrelation. It cites (correctly) that the power is the autocorrelation at tap 0 (i.e. $r_{xx}[0]$) and the integral of the PSD which is the Fourier Transform of the autocorrelation.

Comment: That's true. Thanks! I will use integral over PSD.